# htaccess - # as a string, not as a comment

Tags: .htaccess, comments

I solved this myself: "RewriteRule ^page/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1" in the htaccess and "if($_GET['page']==""{/*javascript who does the scrolling to the target*/}" in the php!

---

I want `http://www.example.com@test` to be changed into `http://www.example.com#test`. That # will be used as a target. My problem is, when rewriting the url, he thinks everything after the # is a comment.
These are the codes I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=page#$1 
RewriteRule ^page/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=page#$1 
RewriteRule ^page@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=page#$1
RewriteRule ^page@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=page#$1 


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=page%23$1 
RewriteRule ^page/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=page%23$1 
RewriteRule ^page@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=page%23$1
RewriteRule ^page@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=page%23$1 


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=page\#$1
RewriteRule ^page/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=page\#$1 
RewriteRule ^page@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=page\#$1
RewriteRule ^page@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=page\#$1
```

How to let htaccess think that # is a string?

Comment: The target doesn't exist to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The information behind the hash sign is not sent to the server. Only the browser can process that information. Therefore there is no point for you to try to match your URL the way you did.

Comment: Thank you, @thephpdeveloper. Because of that I did it with a GET variable in php, wich reads it, and sets the target. :D

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for that, phpdeveloper ;P